# C++ using arguments ARGV

Tags: c++, string

I want to take argv[(2 in this example)], store it into vector and use it later in program. The problem is that no operand matches those operands std::string == int. So does that mean that the app sees '-r' as int? I'm a bit confused here.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::vector<std::string> argList;
    cout<<"argc: "<<argc<<endl;
    for(int i=2; i<=argc; i++)
    {
        argList.push_back(argv[i]);
    }
    if(argList.at(2) == '-r') cout<<" Good job ";
}
```

Comment: You just need double quotes to make a string literal: `"-r"`. With single quotes, it's a literal of type int.

Comment: argv[2] is being placed in argList[0] and argList[2] contains argv[4] so are you passing 4 parameters to your program?  Really you should check the size of the vector before you try to access element 2

Comment: Also a duplicate of / answered by http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3683602/single-quotes-vs-double-quotes-in-c

Comment: @AndrewMedico actually it's of type `char` that can be autoboxed into an int.

Comment: Oops, you're right - one of the differences between C and C++. I wouldn't say "autoboxed" though (maybe "implicitly converted") - C++ doesn't do boxing and `int` isn't an object anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues with your program:

1. You iterate `i` until `i == argc`, that will attempt to construct a string from `argv[argc]`, a NULL pointer due to the requirement by C and C++ standards that `argv[argc]` be 0 (NULL), see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3772796/argvargc).  argv is an array with `argc` pointers to [null-terminated character strings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null-terminated_string) (terminated by ASCII NUL, 0), the array itself is terminated with a NULL pointer (not counted in `argc`).  Now, in C++ you can construct a string from a pointer to a null-terminated character string, but passing a NULL pointer to a string constructor results in undefined behavior, [see this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17464514/initialize-stdstring-from-a-possibly-null-char-pointer), also see the list of std::string constructors [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/string/), you are implicitly using constructor (4) in that list (from c-string).
2. You start pushing onto argList with `i==2`, which means argList[0] will contain `argv[2]`, you then reference `argList.at(2)`, which would correspond to `argv[4]`, this is not likely what you meant.
3. String literals use double quotes

I've corrected these and created a working program, click [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/86d96c14a0f36d3f)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using std::vector;
using std::string;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    vector<string> argList;
    cout << "argc: " << argc << endl;
    for(int i=0; i < argc; ++i)
    {
        argList.push_back(argv[i]);
    }
    cout << "Program name is " << argList[0] << endl;
    if(argc > 1) {
        if(argList.at(1) == "-r") {
            cout << " Good job, you supplied -r\n";
        } else {
            cout << "Unrecognized option " << argList[1]
                << "\nUsage: " << argList[0] << " -r\n";
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "So argv[argc] == NULL" - No, not at all.   `argv[argc]` invokes undefined behavior and you cannot make assumptions as to what that next bit of memory contains.

Comment: Section 3.6.1 of C++ Standard (draft) http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf says "The value of argv[argc] shall be 0."

Comment: Section `5.1.2.2.1 Program startup` of C Standard (draft) http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1124.pdf says "argv[argc] shall be a null pointer."

Comment: @EdS. Also see this SO question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3772796/argvargc

Comment: Oh, wow, I didn't know that.  Thanks, learned something.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your use of single quotes in `'-r'`. You want double quotes here:

```
if(argList.at(2) == "-r") cout<<" Good job ";
```

The reason is that in C++, single quotes are used for *characters* only. There is such a thing as a "multi-byte character constant", which is what `'-r'` ends up being. This is something completely different from a string constant, which is what you want.